# What's the best design pattern for scrolling images in UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, tableview

I've created an app that uses table view to show images. These images are stored in a database. However, currently as it is now, it is not a scalable application because I'm simply querying for 25 images and storing them into an array and putting them in the table view. If I had 100,000 images this would not be practical. What I was thinking to accommodate for a lot of images is the following:

1) First query for 25 images and store it in the array and view it them in table view.

2) Then, as I scroll down the table view I query for the next 25 images while I'm scrolling down.

3) When I scrolled down past the first 25 images, I delete the first 25 images from the beginning.

4) Then, start again at step 1 until there are no more images in the database

If I scroll up, I would just do the opposite, and query for the last 25 images (remembering to put them in reverse order in the array of course).

I'm sure this problem has already been solved before, I'm just not sure if my solution is okay. Do you guys think this is scalable? If not, what problems will I run into doing this and what's a better way to do it? Thank you for your help.

Comment: [`NSFetchedResultsController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/index.html) is Apple's solution.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler pattern would be to load more images once the user has scrolled to the bottom of the app, i.e. once they scroll to the bottom they see a spinner and you load out the next 25 images. You do not need to do anything about deleting older images as they will already be out of memory. This is the pattern I've seen used in many mobile apps and also my own apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign index for each image, load a multiple images each times (the number of images is equal to number of rows). When the user scrolls to bottom:

- Show loading spinner
- Get the index of last image, query the next multiple images set
- Refresh the tableview, hide(stop) the loading spinner

if you have the URL path of image, you can load it asynchronously without freeze the UI.